# Complex Dynamic LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I`m using Linq To Entities to power up my app and i want to create quite a complex search query... see what I want is:

> Upon a user entering a string like "Washington Boston" i will break it in N strings, according to the amount of " "(empty spaces, in this case 2 strings) and search my Counties table for Washington and for Boston

If this were a "static" query i would write it like this:`where  county.Name.Contains("Washington") || county.Name.Contains("Boston")` but i don't know how many cities (or white spaces for this matter) the user will enter...

In a classic pure TSQL enviroment i would compile the query on runtime and use the command Exec... so my question here is: How to dynamically generate a LINQ to entities query?

Please take note that .Where() is not a extension method based on delegates... it does not translate to TSQL on the backend, meaning `from e in context.Counties.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("boston"))` translates to `SELECT ID,NAME FROM COUNTIES` on the backend

Comment: Put the names in a List<string> and then use .Where(q => yourList.Contains(q.Name)) - it will build an SQL IN() statement which from the sound of it is what you are after.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin hummm no... "Boston" is not in "Boston Bla"

Comment: The Contains() method in this case checks the entire value against another entire value, it is not the same thing as a LIKE search in SQL. It equates to am IN() clause in SQL, which again checks entire values, not parts thereof. It just says, if the list contains this value in the database, get me that value. It would not retrieve "Boston Bla"... Before you come up with another rebuttal to my comment, why not try it first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just expand David Khaykin's comment into an answer, because it is the simplest way to achieve the requirement.

You simply need to split the search term into a list of terms, and then filter your `counties` entity using the `Contains` method according to your requirement

```
var terms = searchTerm.Split(' ').ToList();

// an exact match  
counties.Where(c => terms.Contains(c.Name))

// a 'contains' or 'like' type match
counties.Where(c => terms.Any(t => c.Contains(t));
```

The `Contains` method is the [System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx), not `String.Contains`.

When writing any complex dynamic LINQ queries, you can use the method outlined by bmused - very powerful. But for this type of simple filtering you can pass straight lists.

Comment: This answer is better than my one, because it leverages SQL and keeps your code simple. I've tended to use Predicate Builder where I want to search multiple fields in a row for a single value, which is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

you could use [System.Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx)

So you would do something like (Not tested):

```
public Expression<Func<County, Boolean>> GetPredicate(List<String> terms)
{
//The string method - Contains
MethodInfo mContains = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains");

//The parameter - county
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(County), "County");

//The property - Name
Expression property = Expression.Property(pe, "Name");

//expression body
Expression body = null;

foreach(String term in terms)
{
  //the constant to look for
  Expression searchTerm = Expression.Constant(term);

   //build expression body
   if(body == null) body = Expression.Call(property, mContains, searchTerm);
   else body = Expression.OrElse(body, 
       Expression.Call(property, mContains, searchTerm));
}

//create predicate
return Expression.Lambda<Func<County, Boolean>>(body, pe);
}
```

Comment: +1 this quite don't work for my case right here but it's a very good answer... only question is: will it work with Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) (and [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) because you're using Entity Framework), which will let you do this:

```
IQueryable<County> SearchInCountyNames(params string[] countyNames)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<County>();

  foreach (string countyName in countyNames)
  {
    string name = countyName;
    predicate = predicate.Or(c => c.Name.Contains(name));
  }


  return dataContext.Counties.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
}
```

There's a bunch more examples on the predicate builder site.